# Better to Pre-Chip or Randomly-Chip Images for Neural Net Training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have started to dig a little deeper in Tensorflow and Neural Net training with a focus on optimizing run time and keep bumping up against a data ingestion problem.

Lets say I have 30,000 256x256 images that I have created an efficient Tensorflow pipeline for (including pre-fetching and parallel data calls) that randomly chips the image to 64x64 pixels and randomly flips the images in both directions. So the model accepts tensors of shape (batchsize, 64, 64) and via augmentation there are 30000*((256/64)**2)*4 = 1,920,000 minimum examples. Minimum because there at minimum 16 unique chips but many more ways to randomly chip the whole image. The 4 comes from the four possible flip states (Same, Same), (Flipped, Same), (Same, Flipped), (Flipped, Flipped).

I have this model distributed across several GPU's and so batch size isn't limited by available memory, just trade offs with generalization and how accurate the model will be. In this scenario, I was able to get through a single epoch in ~35 seconds with a batch size of 128 (32 examples per GPU).

Now lets imagine another scenario in which I have pre-chipped the data (deterministically, aka every image has 16 non-overlapping chips extracted) and saved chips locally as 64x64 pixel images. In this case, I don't do any random sampling but otherwise the input pipeline is the same. The number of individual files has gone up considerably from 30,000 to 480,000 with a maximum number of unique examples equal to the minimum number of unique examples from the previous setup. Now, because the number of files has gone up, for the same batch size, the training steps has gone up considerably. Even if I double the batch size, training now takes 2-3 minutes per epoch.

I am curious if there is a consensus between these two scenarios. In scenario 1, I would imagine that I would need to train longer than scenario 2, but could also potentially get away with an even bigger batch size since the training data is slightly changing every single epoch (thus less worry about the model not generalizing).

In scenario 2, I imagine that I could get away with training for less epochs at the cost of an individual epoch taking longer. Since the model is seeing every single example each epoch, there is a real limit to how big I can make the batch size without making the model poorer at generalizing.

Is there a consensus on which scenario is best? It seems like Scenario 1 is better in nearly every way, but something keeps nabbing at me that I am missing something.

Comment: In Scenario 2, are you applying the image augmentation?

Comment: Yes, but the augmentation is just flipping at that point. The random chipping is turned off.